Azure Dev Ops - Set variable template based on expression
I am trying to set the variable template to use based on if the branch is dev, release or master using the config below:
pipeline.yml
variables:
  - template: ../vars/global.yml
  - ${{ if eq( variables.isDev , 'True' ) }}:
      - template: ../vars/dev.yml
  - ${{ if eq( variables.isRelease , 'True' ) }}:
      - template: ../vars/stage.yml
  - ${{ if eq( variables.isMaster , 'True' ) }}:
      - template: ../vars/prod.yml


stages:
  - template: ../stages/build.yml
  - template: ../stages/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      dmEnvironment: $(dmEnvironment)
      environment: $(environment)


dev.yml
variables:
  dmEnvironment:         Data-Marketplace-Dev
  environment:           dev

global.yml
variables:

  # Branches
  masterBranch:          refs/heads/master
  developBranch:         refs/heads/an-update-templates
  releaseBranch:         refs/heads/stage

  # Pipeline conditions
  isMaster:              ${{ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables.masterBranch) }}
  isDev:                 ${{ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables.developBranch) }}
  isRelease:             ${{ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables.releaseBranch) }}
  isPR:                  ${{ eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}
  isScheduled:           ${{ eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule') }}
  isManual:              ${{ eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual') }}

deploy.yml
stages:
  - stage: Deployment
    dependsOn: Build
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploymentJob
        environment: $(dmEnvironment)
        timeoutInMinutes: 0
        workspace:
          clean: all
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - template: ../steps/retrieve_akv.yml
                  parameters:
                    azure_service_connection: $(starburstService)
                    key_vault_name: $(starburstKeyVaultName)
                - template: ../steps/tag_successful_deployment.yml
                  parameters:
                    azure_service_connection: $(edlService)
                    tag: $(environment)


But I am getting the error Job Dev: Environment $(dmEnvironment) could not be found. The environment does not exist or has not been authorized for use. So it seems like it's not recognizing my variable. How can I get it to read the actual value?

Where exactly is $(dmEnvironment) being defined/referenced? Are you sure your ${{ if...}} statements are correct and one of the templates (dev, stage or prod) is being referenced?

The error is because the variable dmEnvironment is not defined. It's probably not defined because none of your expressions that reference a template are evaluating to true. Where are the variables isDev, isRelease, etc being set?

You were using macro syntax $(dmEnvironment) to pass variable value in template parameter. The macro syntax expression was processed at runtime and was empty at compile time. You probably also used the template parameter in compile time expression in the template, which incurred this error. Please let us know where & how the variable dmEnvironment is defined and where & how the parameter dmEnvironment is used in your /stages/deploy.yml template, to help understand how the issue is reproduced so that we can assist to modify. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I updated the post with the details

Hi @AnnNguyen, Have you got a chance to check my answer below where the templates are included in a different structure? Hope it works for you.

Based on the update, we could see this pipeline was using variable $(dmEnvironment) in macro syntax to define the environment property of the DeploymentJob in template deploy.yml. This is incorrect because the environment resource should be decided at compile time rather than runtime, while macro syntax variables get processed during runtime after compile time. Therefore, we could only observe the variable name $(dmEnvironment) for environment but not its value, as it was not expanded at compile time. Here is the document to help us Understand variable syntax.
However, even we opt to use compile time template expression like ${{ variables.dmEnvironment ]}, it could only be expanded as empty '', because it was dynamically defined on the condition of ${{ if eq( variables.isDev , 'True' ) }}: in variables block of pipeline.yml.
Per the requirement to dynamically use stage templates with respective variable template, I would suggest modifying the YAML pipeline structure like below.
pipeline.yml - Use conditional insertion to include stage template rather than to include variable template:
variables:
- template: ../vars/global.yml

stages:
- template: ../stages/build.yml
- ${{ if eq( variables.isDev , 'True' ) }}:
  - template: ../stages/deploy.yml

deploy.yml - Expand variable template in stage template and use compile time template expression to define environment resource:
stages:
- stage: Deployment
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
  - template: ../vars/dev.yml # Expand variable template dev.yml inside stage template deploy.yml 
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    environment: ${{ variables.dmEnvironment }} # Use compile time template expression rather than macro syntax
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: |
              echo "dmEnvironment is $(dmEnvironment)" # Use macro syntax of variables at runtime
              echo "environment is $(environment)"


